# Mapping an non-primitive object with Dapper

Tags: orm, dapper

I have the following class

```
    public class Point
    {
        public long Id { get; set; }

        public Address Address { get; set; }
    }
```

I am attempting to have Dapper correctly map the Address data.

```
   var points = this._db.Query<Point>("select * from Points").ToList();
```

My table schema is as follows:

[image: db schema]

Is there any way to specify specific column data to Dapper, in order to map non-primitive objects? 
[image: visual studio debugger image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to correctly map you need to use the multi-map functionality.

```
 var points = this._db.Query<Point, Address, Point>("select p.Id, 'x' [Id], p.Address_City [City], p.Address_State [State] from Points p", (p, a) =>
            {
                p.Address = a;
                return p;
            }).ToList();
```